# Formatting after unique part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I had a string that always had a two letter identifier such as ID or XX, or another variant. The only thing that is consistent is that the identifier is two capital letters.

eg: `Half, ID, Acre`

Is it possible to only add a `<br/>` after the `ID` part of the string with jQuery?

eg `Half, ID,<br/> Acre`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's string manipulation you're after you'd use plain JavaScript, not jQuery.

The following adds `"<br/>"` after any instance of two capital letters in a row followed by a comma:

```
var s = "Half, ID, Acre";

var sWithBR = s.replace(/([A-Z][A-Z],)/g, "$1<br/>");
```

If you also wanted to allow for two capitals at the end of the string with no trailing comma then you could use the following regex instead:

```
/([A-Z][A-Z](,|$))/g
```

If you only want to do the first one, e.g., only change `ID` within `"Half, ID, XY, ZZ, Acre"` just remove the `g` flag from the end of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this - using native JavaScript's .split() and .join():

```
var oldString = "Half, ID, Acre";
var newString = oldString.split('ID,').join('ID,<br/>');
```

Working example here: http://livecoding.io/3495095